# Do users of CRISPR/Cas iterate or parallelize to try multiple guide sequences?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, lab-techniques, crispr, cas9

I've read about on-target efficiency and off-target effects in use of CRISPR/Cas9, and about tools that suggest good guide sequences. I am wondering: how many guide sequences do typical CRISPR users try -- i.e. is there any iteration or parallelism involved?

I think the answer is yes for some use cases, but I am not sure:

- *Knocking out one particular locus*: There are only a few possible guide sequences, so you can just make a library that includes all of those and run one experiment, without iteration. You would not know which guide sequence worked best, though, but users may not need this information.
- *Knocking out one gene, no matter at which loci*: Since there are many possible loci for indels, the key is to choose a locus for which the guide sequence is effective and produces the last off-target effects elsewhere in the genome. This would mean iterating/trying several of the top suggested guide sequences individually. These could be tried in parallel across several experiments.
- *Knocking out multiple genes, aka multiplexing*: The user would want to find good guide sequences for each gene separately to avoid any interactions. This would reduce to the previous example above.

Is my understanding above correct?

Comment: I usually do 2-3 parallel guides for a single gene, but I'm not sure on how common it is.

Comment: @MarchHo Thanks! Do you just use the 2-3 top guides from a guide selection tool like http://crispr.mit.edu/ in parallel, and then report whichever worked best?